# reliable, cross-browser way to get selection's boundaries?

Tags: javascript, textselection

I need to make the user to be able to select some text, click a button and make the server remember the selection for the next time.

I've extensively read through SO's questions and answers, tried some libraries, but without luck: haven't found a reliable tool yet.

It isn't important how the selection's boundaries are identified: it could be "nth textNode, mth char", or "nth char of text", or "nth char of html", or whatever, as long as it allows the server to identify the points in the document; what really matter is that, selecting the same words of the same document must give the same result on chrome, safari, IE, firefox.

**EDIT:** I don't need it to work everywhere on the internet: just on one site, where the document's structure is fixed and only the content of a single div (or the like) will change.

Answer (score 0):

Try my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library and its [Serializer module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule). I'm not convinced it's exactly what you want because you mentioned the server remembering the selection, whereas my suggestion uses cookies, and the serialized selection will vary between browsers. However, it does do as you described in the first paragraph.

On the other hand, it's pretty much impossible to write something that will work for all browsers and all pages, since browsers interpret HTML differently and build different DOMs.

Comment: I've tried Rangy a bit, but it doesn't seem to work correctly on chrome; I wasn't also unable to obtain the same numbers on IE and firefox...

Comment: No, you don't get the same numbers on IE and Firefox, because IE's DOM is different (principally because of IE filtering out whitespace text nodes). I did consider trying to force the same numbers in all browsers but decided there were too many ways in which it could fail. If there's a problem in Chrome the I haven't seen it. The following test page works for me in Chrome: http://www.timdown.co.uk/rangy/test/serializer.html

Comment: I just submitted an issue ( http://code.google.com/p/rangy/issues/detail?id=20 ) about Chrome.

Comment: @giorgian: Thanks, I'll look into it as soon as I can.

Comment: @giorgian: There was a small issue on the demo page, not with the library. I replied on the issue page.